# How to update Prestashop product quantities from a csv file?

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to update stock product from a CSV file containing two columns, reference and quantity, on a Prestashop project, so preferably using prestashop objects, I know I will definitely have to use fgetCSV(), getIdByReference() but I don't really know how to build this, can you help me?

My actual script (who doesn't work I don't know why)
My csv file is on the root of the project, as my php script
my prefix database is basic_

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php';

$remote_csv_file = './product.csv';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=XXXX;port=XXX;dbname="._DB_NAME_."", _DB_USER_, _DB_PASSWD_);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

set_time_limit(600);

$default_qta = 0;
$updateAll = $db->prepare("update basic_product SET quantity = :default_qta");
$updateAll->execute(array(':default_qta'=>$default_qta));

$updateAll = $db->prepare("update basic_product_attribute SET quantity = :default_qta");
$updateAll->execute(array(':default_qta'=>$default_qta));

$updateAll = $db->prepare("update basic_stock_available SET quantity = :default_qta");
$updateAll->execute(array(':default_qta'=>$default_qta));

$row_num = 0;
if (($handle = fopen($remote_csv_file, "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
        $row_num++;
        if ($row_num == 1) {
            // Passer la premiere ligne
            continue;
        }
        if ($data[0] == '' || !is_numeric($data[1])) {
            // skip les valeurs vides
            continue;
        }

        $reference = trim($data[0]);
        $quantity  = ($data[1] >= 0) ? $data[1] : 0;

        try {
            $res4 = $db->prepare("SELECT id_product, id_product_attribute from "._DB_PREFIX_."product_attribute WHERE reference = :reference");
            $res4->execute(array(':reference'=>$reference));

            if ($res4->rowCount() > 0) {

                $row4 = $res4->fetch();

                $res = $db->prepare("update basic_stock_available set quantity = :q where id_product_attribute = :id_product_attribute");
                $res->execute(array(':q'=>$quantity, ':id_product_attribute'=>$row4['id_product_attribute']));

                $res = $db->prepare("update basic_product_attribute set quantity = :q where id_product_attribute = :id_product_attribute");
                $res->execute(array(':q'=>$quantity, ':id_product_attribute'=>$row4['id_product_attribute']));

                $res = $db->prepare("update basic_stock_available set quantity = quantity + :q where id_product = :id_product and id_product_attribute = 0");
                $res->execute(array(':q'=>$quantity, ':id_product'=>$row4['id_product']));

                $res = $db->prepare("update "._DB_PREFIX_."product set quantity = quantity + :q where id_product = :id_product");
                $res->execute(array(':q'=>$quantity, ':id_product'=>$row4['id_product']));

            } else {

                $res4 = $db->prepare("SELECT id_product from basic_product WHERE reference = :reference");
                $res4->execute(array(':reference'=>$reference));
                if ($res4->rowCount() > 0) {
                    $row4 = $res4->fetch();

                    $res = $db->prepare("update basic_stock_available set quantity = :q where id_product = :id_product and id_product_attribute = 0");
                    $res->execute(array(':q'=>$quantity, ':id_product'=>$row4['id_product']));

                    $res = $db->prepare("update basic_product set quantity = :q where id_product = :id_product");
                    $res->execute(array(':q'=>$quantity, ':id_product'=>$row4['id_product']));
                }

            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Sql Error: '. $e->getMessage() .'<br /><br />';
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stock feed" ?

Comment: Excuse me, bad translation, I mean I will update stock product from information in a CSV file contains just Reference & Quantity

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't update the row directly on the database. Using the built-in method from the `StockAvailable` class is much better. Take a look here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.8.x/classes/stock/StockAvailable.php#L546

The second thing is that there might be a situation where you have a reference provided for the product but not for the combination.